# Server Local Users only allowed access to my site, please help

Tags: asp.net, iis

My deadline to have my site up is soon, and I can't figure out why the server is only letting it's local users access the site's directory! IE is showing me this box before I can even connect to the site:
[image]
I have tried everything I can think of, enabling/disabling Anonymous access, integrated windows authentication, messing with < authorization >/< identity > tags in web.config and I can't figure it out! Has anyone ran into this problem before and know how to fix it?? BTW, this is an intranet/internal site only.
Sorry if not enough info, I need to have this up in the next 20 min ><; I'll provide any additional info needed..

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a NT file permissions problem. IUSR_ needs to have file system permissions to read whatever file you're requesting (like /inetpub/wwwroot/index.htm).

Comment: I have the IUSR, the one set for anonymous access, set for Read permissions. Nothing

Answer (score 0):

Turn of all authentication except for Anonymous.

Other authentication types direct the browser to authenticate even if anonymous access is configured.

Comment: If I uncheck "Integrated Windows Authentication", I don't even get the Login Dialogue (above pic); IE just tells me I'm not authorized to view this page

Comment: Try viewing a page through a direct url.  

Ensure you have default documents enabled and specify a matching default document (such as 'default.aspx').

Comment: That's all already setup, and yea I'm trying to access thru direct url. and default doc is setup